# apps script dashboard in HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script, dashboard

I saw the dashboard demo, and it looks amazing. Is it possible to embed a dashboard and even charts in a user interface created using HtmlService? Most of the demos are only using UI Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand for now the only library you are able to use is JQuery and JQuery UI library but I believe the team are adding in more library to support it.